# Changing an index of 2d tensor by elements of 1d tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

Can someone explain me how can I solve my problem: I have 2d tensor like

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8]]
```

and 1d tensor `[0, 1, 1, 0]` and I wanna change elements in 2d tensor by index by value in 1d tensor. For example, in 2d tensor above I need:

```
[[0, 2],
 [3, 0],
 [5, 0],
 [0, 8]]
```

I tried doing something like `torch.where` but I don't know how can I use `torch.where` with 2d and 1d tensor in the same time. Thank you in advance

Comment: For the 1d, are those column numbers (possibky bigger than 1, or boolean, just False.True?

Comment: @hpaulj Boolean

Comment: Assuming that the new values after replacement would be 0, `original_tensor[torch.arange(original_tensor.size(0)), oneD_tensor] = 0` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [194]: arr = np.arange(1,9).reshape(4,2);arr
Out[194]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

In [195]: msk = np.array([0,1,1,0])
```

Interpreting the `msk` values as integers, column numbers, we can select 4 values with:

```
In [196]: arr[np.arange(4),msk]
Out[196]: array([1, 4, 6, 7])
```

and set those values to 0:

```
In [197]: x=arr.copy(); x[np.arange(4),msk] = 0; x
Out[197]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [0, 8]])
```

Or as boolean values:

```
In [198]: msk = msk.astype(bool);msk
Out[198]: array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

Use it to selectively copy values by column:

```
In [199]: res = np.zeros_like(arr)    
In [200]: res[msk,0]=arr[msk,0]    
In [201]: res[~msk,1]=arr[~msk,1]    
In [202]: res
Out[202]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [0, 8]])
```

There may be a way of condensing that action, but with boolean values there are only 2 column copies.

```
In [204]: arr*np.stack([msk,~msk],1)
Out[204]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [0, 8]])
```

I can't think of a way of avoiding at least one `~msk`.